# Laravel 8: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my forum project.

So I have made a table named `tags` that contains some hashtags and the other one is `questions` that holds some questions that has been asked on the forum.

I also created another table named `tag_question` that shows each `question_id` is using which `tag_id`, as this image shows:

[image: capture]

So in order to make this relation, I added this to the Model `Tag`:

```
public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class);
    }
```

And this one to the Model `Question`:

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }
```

Now for inserting questions with custom tags, I added this method:

```
public function postForm()
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'private' => 'nullable',
            'category' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'array|required',
        ])->validated();

        $question = Question::create($validate_data);

        $question->tags()->sync(request('tags'));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

`request('tags')` is getting from this select option on the blade:

```
<label for="topic" class="BKoodakBold">Tags:</label>
   <select class="form-control BSinaBold" name="tags[]" id="skills" multiple>
       @foreach(\App\Models\Tag::all() as $tag)
           <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
```

Now the problem is, whenever I try to insert a new question, this error appears:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> **SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.question_tag' doesn't exist

So what's going wrong here? Why am I receiving this issue and how to solve it?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling the belongsToMany() with only one parameter assumes the name of the pivot table.

So you have two options,

- Either change the name of the pivot table to match the laravel/eloquent convention, which is "the two related model names in alphabetical order." (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure)
  So in your case that would be renaming `tag_question` to `question_tag`
- Or you can explicitly set the name in the pivot table as a second parameter of the `belongsToMany()` method,

that would be:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'tag_question');
}
```

And

```
enpublic function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_question');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You called your pivot table tag_question but Laravel is looking for question_tag. Try renaming your table to: question_tag